# Cannot assign a string value from nextLine() in Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to understand why `inputString` is still empty after executing this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

    int inputInt = 0;
    double inputDouble = 0.0;
    String inputString = null;

    Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (scanner3.hasNext()) {
        inputInt = scanner3.nextInt();
    }


    if (scanner3.hasNext()) {
        inputDouble = scanner3.nextDouble();
    }

    if (scanner3.hasNext()) {
        inputString = scanner3.nextLine();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("No entries left");
    }

    System.out.println("String: " + inputString);
    System.out.println("Double: " + inputDouble);
    System.out.println("Int: " + inputInt);
}
```

Comment: Add an extra `scanner3.nextLine();` before you call `nextLine`

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/1371499) for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextLine()` read new line character before read your character. Add a extra `nextLine()` to read that new line.

```
 if (scanner3.hasNext()) {
        scanner3.nextLine();
        inputString = scanner3.nextLine();
 }
```